# How do you rotate a bar graph 180 degrees in Dash?

Tags: python, html, css, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm working with Dash right now, and I want to rotate a bar graph 180 degrees. There is no in-built way using plot.ly to completely invert a bar graph, so I assume it must be done using the external stylesheet.

Right now, I'm using the external stylesheet here: https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP

I've tried adding:

```
div#rotate {transform: rotate(180deg); }
```

To the external stylesheet and then add:

```
html.Div(children = "test", id = "rotate")
```

To my Dash app layout, but when I run the script, the "test" text is still normally orientated. How can I implement a 180 degree rotated bar graph to me Dash application?

Comment: Have you tried uploading it to webfaction?

Comment: I haven’t tried that - but running it locally doesn’t show the change encoded in the html.Div() line in the python script. Is there a reason the local deployment would not be displaying specific encoded elements?